# Bower - Give different path to a registered package

Tags: node.js, git, repository, bower, bower-install

I have my own cloned git repository.
(*I'll use cloned jquery to simplify*)

I want to be able to link a  **Registered** package name to a given path so I could do this:

> "jquery": "1.0.0"

---

**I know it is possible to just give the path, i.e**

> bower install myJqueryPath

**OR**, add to dependencies on bower.json

> "jquery": "myJqueryPath"

---

But again, these solutions are not what i'm looking for.
I want to let bower know not to install jquery (or any other package) from github. But to install to it from a given repository.

Thanks :)

(I know it is possible, i don't know how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after further review, the secret lies in the **.bowerrc** file.
The **.bowerrc** file has a field called **registry** which is responsible for telling bower:

> My man, go look for packages in the following link:

It's  supposed to look something like this:

```
  {
     "registry": {
        "search": [
           "http://localhost:8080/"
        ]
     }
  }
```

This tells bower to go search for packages in some kind of a copy to  [bower's default repository](https://bower.herokuapp.com/). ([jquery example](https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery)).

Now, when bower knows to go look for packages in my path instead of it's default path I can finally use:

> bower install jquery

and, as wanted, it will install it from my path.
plus, I can add bower's defualt repository as my second option.

*small note:

  using* `"registry": "http://localhost:8080/"` *is also fine*.